# Mapping over observable

Tags: angular, mapping, observable

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around filtering an observable.

I have a widget

```
{name: string, description: string}
```

I have an observable of widgets

```
[{},{},{}]
```

I want to loop over my widgets observable but widgets.map() doesn't loop over each individual widget in the observable but the entire observable.

```
widgets.map((widget) => {console.log(widget.name)}) is always undefined.
```

What am I not understanding?

Comment: Please, provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If the value is `widgets` array, it should be iterated like usual.

Answer (score 0):

Your Obserable returns an Array of Widgets, not every widget by itself. You have to map on the array that is returned.

```
widgets.map((widgets) => widgets.map(widget => console.log(widget)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an observable from your widgets.

`Observable.from(widgets).subscribe(res => console.log(res));`

Remember you can create observables from different types of streams.